# using Properties to read .properties files

Tags: java, linux, servlets, properties

I need to be able to read properties files using FileInoputStream.
I have 3 properties files:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
Properties props2 = new Properties();
Properties props3 = new Properties();
FileInputStream ldapfis = new FileInputStream("/home/webserver/tomcat6/properties/js.ldap.properties");
FileInputStream smtpfis = new FileInputStream("/home/webserver/tomcat6/properties/js.smtp.properties");
FileInputStream dbfis   = new FileInputStream("/home/webserver/tomcat6/properties/js.db.properties");    

props.load(ldapfis);
props2.load(smtpfis);
props2.load(dbfis);

String host = props.getProperty("ldap.provider.host");  
String dbName = props2.getProperty("db.name");
```

Is this how you do it in linux with absolute path?
Is this ok to do?

Comment: If you're expecting a *yes*, then *yes* it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new FileInputStream("/home/webserver/tomcat6/properties/js.ldap.properties");
```

If a file path startswith slash (/) it will take this as a path.

but if file path is not startswith slash(/) , then it is a absolute path. It will try to append path with java home.

For Ex

```
new FileInputStream("properties/js.ldap.properties");
```

It will append java path home

Here if java home is `/home/webserver/tomcat6/` it will try to find under `/home/webserver/tomcat6/properties/js.ldap.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really OK to do this, because if you install tomcat in any other location, or even upgrade from tomcat6 to tomcat7, all your code will break.

I would recommend using the `System.getProperty("CATALINA_HOME")` which should point to your tomcat home directory.  You can then get a path based on that.